# How do I read user input in python thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to read from a thread in python as follows

```
import threading, time, random

var = True

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        global var
        while var == True:
            print "In mythread " + self.name
            time.sleep(random.randint(2,5))


class MyReader(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global var
        while var == True:
            input = raw_input("Quit?")
            if input == "q":
                var = False



t1 = MyThread()
t1.set_name("One")

t2 = MyReader()

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

However, if I enter 'q', I see the following error.

```
In mythread One
Quit?q
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 522, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test.py", line 20, in run
    input = raw_input("Quit?")
EOFError

In mythread One
In mythread One
```

How does on get user input from a thread?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit strange.  If you are using the reader strictly to quit the program, why not have it outside the threading code entirely?  It doesn't need to be in the thread, for your purposes, and won't work in the thread.

Regardless, I don't think you want to take this road.  Consider this problem: multiple threads stop to ask for input simultaneously, and the user types input.  To which thread should it go?  I would advise restructuring the code to avoid this need.

Answer (score 0):

Also all read /writes to var should locked