# specific thread exit in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using a thread to create an interruptible, which sends the KeyboardInterrupt command when a specific key is pressed.  After this process I again use the msvcrt.getch() function.  the problem is that the thread won't exit until I have pressed the key once.  Ie the countdown function finishes but the the thread is still waiting for the input for the msvcrt.getch() function.

I tried putting exit.thread() at the end of the countdown function, but that exited the main thread. Do I need to use threading instead of thread?

```
import time, thread, msvcrt

print "enter time for timer"
n=raw_input()

def input_thread():
    z=msvcrt.getch()
    if z == "a" :   
        thread.interrupt_main()
    if z != "a" :
        thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, ())
        print "nope"
        thread.exit()

def countdown(n):
    try:
        thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, ())
        for i in range(int(n)):
            c = int(n) - int(i)
            print c ,'seconds left','\r',
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "I was rudly interrupted"

countdown(n)
print """

"""
k=msvcrt.getch()
if k == "k" :
    print "you typed k"
else :
    print "you did not type K"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757318/how-do-i-read-user-input-in-python-thread

Comment: `Do I need to use threading instead of thread?` Yes.  `threading` is the high-level API, `thread` is low-level.

Comment: use t = threading.Thread(target=input_thread)

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most beautiful way, but it works.

```
from concurrent.futures import thread
import threading
import time, msvcrt

print("enter time for timer")
n=input()

def input_thread():
   z=msvcrt.getch()
   if z == "a" :
       thread.interrupt_main()
   if z != "a" :
       thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, ())
       print ("nope")
       thread.exit()

def countdown(n):
try:
    threading.Thread(target=input_thread)
    for i in range(int(n)):
        c = int(n) - int(i)
        print (c ,'seconds left','\r')
        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("I was rudly interrupted")

countdown(n)
print ("")
k=msvcrt.getch()
if k == "k" :
    print("you typed k")
else :
    print ("you did not type K")
```